# how to debug reflex-dom programs-

Tags: haskell, reflex, reflex-dom

So I just discovered this library and thought it might be awesome for building UI's. Here is a small exercise I tried to implement when learning this library. Basically it tries to open a directory on the local file system and displays all the files in this directory. It compiles with no problem but when I open the `index.html` it just shows a blank page. I have no idea how to debug the program. Here is the code:

```
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}
import           Reflex.Dom
import qualified Data.Text as T
import           System.Directory
import           System.FilePath
import           Control.Monad
import           Data.List (map)


main :: IO ()
main = do
  files <- getDirectoryContents "/"
  let names = map (T.pack . show) files
  mainWidget $ body  names

body :: MonadWidget t m => [T.Text] ->  m ()
body files = el "div" $ do
  el "h2" $ text "Reflex File Test"
  el "ul" $ do
    let lables = map text files
    mapM_ (el "li")  lables
```

Comment: Does anything show up if you don't try to use `getDirectoryContents`?

Comment: yes. for example, if I hard code `names=["1","2","3"]`, everything just works.

Comment: For an introduction to reflex-dom, you can read [this tutorial](https://github.com/hansroland/reflex-dom-inbits)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A good first step in debugging ghcjs problems is to check the browser console.  In this case you will see : `"/: getDirectoryContents: failed (operation unsupported on this platform)"` .

This makes sense.  The code is running in the browser - not on the server, or directly on the client.  So the whole file system concept does not really apply here.

Comment: Cf. [the shim for `System.Directory`](https://github.com/ghcjs/shims/blob/6fb94ef2e0aa93dc862cef2fa98d440b14184a2c/pkg/directory.js) in GHCJS, in which functions appear (if I'm interpreting that correctly) to be enabled or disabled depending on whether the code is built targeting Node or the browser.

Comment: So a backend like yesod or happstack is must if one wants do access local file system?

Comment: You can compile reflex with ghc instead of ghcjs to produce a standalone executable that can access the local file system.  If you run your program in this mode then it shows directory contents.